# Change target duplicate for question I closed

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I closed [this question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24618740/372643) as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730236/372643). This was done with my "gold badge power".

Someone also made a reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2640691/372643) in a comment (this is a comment to the answer that was written just before I closed the question), which I think is a better duplicate (the steps in the answers are similar, but the questions aren't quite the same).

I've just voted to re-open<sup>*</sup> so as to re-close it with another duplicate. I hadn't realised I would be unable to do so. I'm now told that I've already voted and can't do it again.

Is this intended behaviour? I understand that's the case for normal votes, but gold-badge duplicate closing isn't really a vote as such (although it uses the same UI).

<sub>(*) There was also a single vote to re-open (I'm not sure why, no one made an argument for it).</sub>

Comment: It should behave more like mod binding votes, especially if the same user votes to close then reopen...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's intended behavior.

Gold-badge duplicate closing is really a close vote; it just happens to be *binding.*  All of the other rules that apply to ordinary close votes are still preserved.

Comment: Not sure that makes sense for gold-badge close as duplicates, though. I can't understand why it may be implemented as a close vote, but in reality it isn't, it's just my decision that dictates the outcome (at least without involving mods). If anything that will make me far more reluctant to vote to close for duplicates, when I'm not 100% sure it is an *exact* duplicate.

Comment: Bruno, if you had unlimited duplicate votes on a single question, what's to stop you from constantly re-closing the question even after the rest of the community votes to reopen, again and again?

Comment: @Troyen, that makes sense, but I'd like to be able to re-cast *my* vote (or at least change the target duplicate).

Comment: Thanks for changing the duplicate, btw.

Comment: This whole thing seems to put into light some power "imbalance". By having a gold badge on certain tags, I almost have mod powers (when it comes to duplicates) on those tags. Yet, my actions carry more responsibility than those of mods, because I can't fix what I get wrong. I'm the only gold badge holder on the [tag:ssl] tag, and I've been active on it for about 4 years. I have at least a vague memory of many past questions, which is useful for looking for duplicates. However, because of this, I think I'll use this feature much less unfortunately, which probably wasn't the intended effect.

Comment: @Bruno: You're not the only gold badge owner, y'know.

Comment: On that tag, I am.

Comment: Ah, well I don't think you need 100% certainty of duplication.  95% ought to be more than sufficient.